# How to customize exporting query result (PHP mysql) to excel file?

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-excel

I have some questions about customizing export result(excel) with php. The idea is i want to export my query of my raw data (mysql table) to excel file but with some customization in the result.
for example i want to have result which is summary of the table like below table:
[image]

The 3rd column until 7th column is named based on the last 5 days of my report date.

My idea is:
1. create temporary table using format as the result table i want to generate
2. Insert the table with my raw data.
3. Delete those table.

Is that efective?or is there any better idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a view. Which is essentially a select statement with your data in there, and which will be updated whenever your tables are updated. Then you can just do a '`select * from view_name`' and export that into your excel.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the data, there is no need to think about performance.

## Edit the data before

You can have a temp table. Depending on the data, this is very fast if you can select and insert the data based on indexes. Then you make a `SELECT * from tmp_table;` and you have all your data

## Edit the data after

You can just join over the different tables, get the data and then loop (read as `foreach`) over the result array and change the data and export it afterwards